# Cannot resolve isConnected() - Google+ login on android studio

Tags: android, authentication, build

I created a new activity to handle logging into my app. I selected login activity from the template menu and ticked include google+ sign in. Upon building the activity I'm met with the problem "cannot resolve isConnected()" found from the supplied

`boolean connected = getPlusClient().isConnected();`

I've tried rebuilding project and cleaning project but to no avail. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: can you paste your getPlusClient() method please.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using a new version of google play service, where the PlusClient class doesn't exist anymore.
Follow this up to date tutorial instead: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in